# TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function. Movie clip on flash Builder 4.6

Tags: flash, builder, movieclip

I need when a movie clip ends or reach to an x frame or label start a function.
How could i do it?

I tried this and some other codes:

```
if (PresentacionVideo.currentFrame("fin"))
    {
        trace("Termino Animacion");
        stage.removeChild(PresentacionVideo);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);
    }
```

But its not working, it says:

> TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.
And sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
if (PresentacionVideo.currentFrameLabel == "fin")
        {
            trace("Termino Animacion");
            stage.removeChild(PresentacionVideo);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);
        }
```

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. I am really a noob Lol.
Thanks you.